# html image not appearing

Tags: html, css

I have the following line of code:

```
<IMG SRC= "Home.png">
```

I copied this directly from a different part of my code that worked. However, now the home image won't show up on my site. It says it prints it, but it's not visible. What's going on?

edit:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userInfo']['username'])){
    echo '<div class = "header"><a href = "mainPage.php"><IMG SRC= "Home.png" ALT="image"></a>  
    <a href = "myProfile.php"><IMG SRC= "ViewProfile.png" ALT="image"></a>  <a href="cartContents.php"><IMG SRC= "ViewCart.png" ALT="image"></a>';
    echo '</div>';
else{
    echo '<div class = "header">
    <IMG SRC= "Home.png">
    <IMG SRC= "FAQ.png"></div>';
  }
```

Comment: Are the two locations in the code (where you copied from and where you copied to) in the same directory?

Comment: Yup. Same folder and everything. It's essentially like, 2 lines down. A different image is displayed depending on a condition.

Comment: @longlost10 It would be best to post the condition then, since there is nothing wrong with what you just posted. (Other than using caps.. lol)

Comment: I added the condition, and the first if statement works just fine. Everything in the else statement doesn't print at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing parenthesis `}` for the **if** statement. That might be the problem.

Try this...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userInfo']['username'])){
    echo '<div class = "header"><a href = "mainPage.php"><IMG SRC= "Home.png" ALT="image"></a>  
    <a href = "myProfile.php"><IMG SRC= "ViewProfile.png" ALT="image"></a>  <a href="cartContents.php"><IMG SRC= "ViewCart.png" ALT="image"></a>';
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class = "header">
    <IMG SRC= "Home.png">
    <IMG SRC= "FAQ.png"></div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="Home.png"/>
  <img src="FAQ.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I do have the opening bracket there. And I'm aware it's supposed to print only once. But something's preventing it from printing it when the condition is false.

Comment: No. I looked at the source code on Chrome and Firefox and it says it's being printed, it's just not showing up

Comment: @longlost10 I updated my solution, please try that. Only think I can think of is including a self closing slash, some older browsers get tripped up due to that. Also, check to make sure you don't have any CSS making that markup invisible.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a broken image icon on the browser?

One thing might be that Home.png is in another directory. Did you copy this code from the same file or another file (possibly located in another directory)? If you copied this code from a file located in another directory you will need to format the image source link accordingly.

For example say you have a directory structure like so:

-index.htm (File)
-Home.png (File)
-js (Directory)
-css (Directory)
-pages (Directory)
---example.htm (File inside Pages directory)

If you then copied the code from your index.htm file to the example.htm located in your pages directory you would need to modify the link in the example.htm page like so:

```
<img src="../Home.png" />
```

Note the ".." which tells the browser to look in one directory up from where your html page is located.

Comment: It's painful that you haven't read the comments. We have already figured out that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score -1):

be sure that the image and file in the same folder
and be sure that the name of image Home with H as capital letter

Comment: Read the asking comments before answering, please.